# When running an arbitrary quantum circuit, can all of the entanglement be done up front?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit

I'm trying to think practically about how a circuit might get implemented on a real world quantum computer and have a specific question about circuit set-up.  Imagine my computer is such that I can only probabilistically create entanglement.  Thus, rather than trying to perform entanglement steps mid-circuit, I rather try and create a bunch of entangled pairs in advance and then - depending on which qubits were pairwise entangled - perform the circuit using those pairs.

Is it possible to reformulate any circuit such that it can be run with qubits that were entangled in the first step?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. What you are looking for is called Measurement-based quantum computing, also called one-way quantum computing.

The wikipedia page is quite instructive https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_quantum_computer